# Minecraft Java Virtual Machine Error

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

When I got my new HP dv7t Quad Edition 17" laptop, I immediately got Java and Minecraft (and Chrome). I opened Minecraft and awaited the famous login screen. I was then surprised with the following error.

[image]

In my opinion, I feel the Java 7 VM is to blame. If it is, **how do I play Minecraft** while Mojang or Oracle work on a new version?

**EDIT**: I have an NVIDIA GeForce GT 630M.

Comment: 7 Update 7 works fine for me.  I don't think I have any other versions installed ATM, since nothing else is showing up in Add/Remove Programs for me.

Comment: How do I downgrade to Java 6?

Comment: That sounds messy. Is there a way I can connect Minecraft to use Java 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note** - *Assuming your PC is a 64-bit machine* -

Are you running 64-bit Java? I've been having a lot of issues running MineCraft on 32-bit java - The game will play fine for about 5 minutes and then lag out (checking the memory usage it gets to about 1GB)

I'd say uninstall Java, and then go to http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp and select the 64-bit version manually.

If you want to check if your PC is 64-bit:

- Click *Start*
- Right-Click *Computer* and select *Properties*.

Under the System section it should say whether it is 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Open Minecraft using MC patcher. You won't be able to play as your user account, but you will be able to play, and install mods easier.